# no php/asp/scripts to send a form

Tags: php, html, asp

'm working on developing a server in java to embed it into a new programming language as a part of run time support. I don't want php/asp or any script support, but I need to send requests from html pages and get responses( like forms) is there any way i can just use html/ java script without any support from server side script ?

How did people use web forms before php/asp were discovered?

Comment: They used Perl or C.

Comment: I have lost you at the first sentence.

Comment: well I'm developing a web server written in java to support a new programming language called system jane i need the server to be responsive ,i.e; taking form data and responding but it cannot support php/asp .. so i need a simpler solution

Comment: You have Java but you're not using JSP?

Comment: well, the sever is wholly in one java file. So I'm basically confused on how to add asp support to it

Answer (score 0):

> but I need to send requests from html pages

The *only* way to have a website send requests is either by the visitor going to another page or by an asynchronous call by Javascript. This is done using [XHR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XMLHttpRequest), or using more advanced frameworks like doing a [`jQuery.post`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) (or `get` depending on the type of request you want to sent).